# Why are Abiword documents flickering since the upgrade to Lubuntu 16?

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, flicker, abiword

Lubuntu offered to upgrade itself the other day. I think I was on 14-something and now it's 16-something. All well and good but now all Abiword docs are flickering constantly. (I've noticed it doesn't happen with a new document until something is typed in it). It's pretty annoying.

Is there a way to fix this?

**Please note: I really like the Linux ethos and I admire anyone with geek-skills but I am computer illiterate so PLEASE DUMB DOWN FOR ME!!

Comment: Use the Adwaita theme. You won't see flashing then.

Comment: if that's an answer @DKBose why don't you write one, with easy peasy instructions ;)

Comment: Thanks DK Bose and Zanna. I tried it out by searching for 'install adwaita theme lubuntu 16' and ended up here [https://pkgs.org/ubuntu-16.04/ubuntu-universe-i386/adwaita-icon-theme-full_3.18.0-2ubuntu3_all.deb.html] and clicked under Binary Package but then it reads: Error: a later version is already installed. Just when I thought things were going swimmingly. Oh well, thanks anyway.

Comment: Install gnome-themes-standard

Comment: Which version of Lubuntu did you install, 16.04.1, 16.04.2 or 16.10? If you tell me, I can test if and how to select theme in Lubuntu to get rid of the flickering. Otherwise, if your computer has enough horsepower and RAM, you can install LibreOffice (which is not affected by that flickering bug).

Answer (score 7):

My workaround is:

**Menu > Preferences > Customize Look and Feel**

Change the Widget theme to anything BUT Lubuntu

Comment: I tried changing the widget theme to Clearlooks but it didn't resolve this issue for me.

Comment: *Abiword v3.0.2-2* still flickers with *Crux*, *Raleigh*, & *Redmond* also.

Comment: I changed the widget theme to Clearlooks and there is no more flickering in Abiword.

Answer (score 4):

[This fix posted on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2362340&highlight=abiword) worked for me on lubuntu 17.04 with kernel 4.10.0-28-generic (x86_64)

> First, please try
>
> ```
> GTK_THEME=Adwaita abiword from a terminal. If that works,
>
> GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark abiword and see if you like that better.
> ```
>
> You can make a `.desktop` file and that will allow you to double-click
>   on the Abiword icon or on an Abiword file to open it with the Adwaita
>   theme:
>
> Save it as `~/.local/share/applications/abiword.desktop` with this content:
>
> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Exec=bash -c 'GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark abiword %U'
> Icon=abiword
> Terminal=false
> Type=Application
> Categories=Office;WordProcessor;GNOME;GTK;X-Red-Hat-Base;
> StartupNotify=true
> X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.9
> MimeType=application/x-abiword;text/x-abiword;text/x-xml-abiword;text/plain;application/msword;application/rtf;application/vnd.plain;application/xhtml+xml;text/html;application/x-crossmark;application/docbook+xml;application/x-t602;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web;application/vnd.sun.xml.writer;application/vnd.stardivision.writer;text/vnd.wap.wml;application/wordperfect6;application/wordperfect5.1;application/vnd.wordperfect;application/x-abicollab;application/vnd.palm;application/x-applix-word;application/x-kword;application/x-mif;application/x-mswrite;application/x-palm-database;text/abiword;text/richtext;text/rtf;
> Name=AbiWord
> GenericName=Word Processor
> Comment=Compose, edit, and view documents
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bugfix in 17.10, so that Abiword works (without flickering) in Lubuntu when using the standard theme.

This is Abiword version 3.0.2-4 according to `apt-cache`

```
$ apt-cache policy abiword
abiword:
  Installed: 3.0.2-4
  Candidate: 3.0.2-4
  Version table:
 *** 3.0.2-4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```